# How do I apply the background gradient color map 'RdYlGn' to some table rows, and it's reverse 'RdYlGn_r' to other rows in the same table?

Tags: python, css, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I have a csv file that I'm reading into jupyter notebook and styling there. The csv data is as follows:

```
[[' ', 'VZ', 'T', 'TMUS'],
['Current Ratio', 1.4, 0.8, 1.1],
['Quick Ratio', 1.3, 0.8, 1.0],
['Debt to Equity', 1.9, 0.97, 1.17],
['LT Debt to Equity', 1.82, 0.95, 1.09],
['ROA', 6.1, 2.0, 1.8],
['ROI', 10.9, 1.7, 4.1],
['Gross Margin', 59.5, 52.7, 59.6],
['Oper. Margin', 19.1, 13.0, 9.7],
['Profit Margin', 14.1, 6.3, 4.5]]
```

The code I've tried is:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/broderickbonelli/Desktop/test.csv', index_col=" ")

data = data.style.background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn').set_precision(2).background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn_r', subset=(data.index[2], data.columns)).background_gradient(cmap='RdYlGn_r', subset=(data.index[3], data.columns))

display(data)
```

The first background gradient with color map 'RdYlGn' applies perfectly, however when I chain the background_gradient() function to apply to specific rows using the subset attribute, and apply the reverse color map 'RdYlGn_r', the gradient does not apply correctly as all values are the same color:

[image: Table with 'RdYlGn' applied correctly, but 'RdYlGn_r' applied incorrectly]

The 'Debt to Equity' and 'LT Debt to Equity' rows are not being applied correctly for some reason. I've also tried adjusting the range using the high and low attributes for the background_gradient() method but it hasn't worked. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to chain the background gradient method for each row and target as subset:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('/Users/broderickbonelli/Desktop/test.csv', index_col=" ", na_values='-')

data = data.style.background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn', subset=(data.index[0], data.columns)).background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn', subset=(data.index[1], data.columns)).background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn_r', subset=(data.index[2], data.columns)).background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn_r', subset=(data.index[3], data.columns)).background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn', subset=(data.index[4], data.columns)).background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn', subset=(data.index[5], data.columns)).background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn', subset=(data.index[6], data.columns)).background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn', subset=(data.index[7], data.columns)).background_gradient(axis=1, cmap='RdYlGn', subset=(data.index[8], data.columns)).set_precision(2)
display(data)
```